# Fast split/indexing of numpy arrays in Cython

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a function that takes in 3 numpy arrays (one 2-d and two 1-d), a column, and a value, and I want to split the numpy arrays the same based on the value in the first array. I was trying to see if I could make this faster by using Cython, but I am getting a bit confused on using typing and using numpy arrays in Cython. The Python code is running faster.

```
cpdef divide_set(np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] x,
                 np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] y,
                 np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] t,
                 int col, value):

    cdef int num = len(t) ndim=1, cast=True] idx1 = x[:, col] >= value
    cdef np.ndarray[np.npy_bool, ndim=1, cast=True] idx2 = ~idx1

    size1 = idx1.sum()
    size2 = idx2.sum()

    cdef np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] x1 = x[idx1]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=2] x2 = x[idx2]

    cdef np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] y1 = y[idx1]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] y2 = y[idx2]

    cdef np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] t1 = t[idx1]
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float_t, ndim=1] t2 = t[idx2]

    return x1, x2, y1, y2, t1, t2
```

Using only numpy/python I had this solution (for reference):

```
def divide_set(x, y, t, col, value):

    idx1 = x[:, col] >= value
    idx2 = ~idx1

    x1 = x[idx1]
    x2 = x[idx2]

    y1 = y[idx1]
    y2 = y[idx2]

    t1 = t[idx1]
    t2 = t[idx2]

    return x1, x2, y1, y2, t1, t2
```

And I would run an example like:

```
from util import divide_set
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random(size=(1000, 10))
y = np.random.random(size=(1000,))
t = np.random.random(size=(1000,))
divide_set(x, y, t, 0, 0.5)
```

Comment: That's because the entire thing is "whole array operations". These are already written in C inside Numpy and are pretty efficient. Cython only really speeds up things like loops while looking up single elements. All you've added is a bunch of type-checks and therefore Cython is slower

Comment: (Plus an unnecessary calculation of the sum in the Numpy code). It would probably be possible to write a slightly faster version by allocating empty arrays then looping element by element (you'd avoid making the index arrays and be able to do everything in one loop) but someone else can do that if they want...